# Most efficient way to calculate possible combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

So I just had discussion with a friend about a theoretical situation were he was to populate a server mother board with ram modules in his garage..

So lets assume there are 48 ram slots available to populate each with one of the 7 different capacities of ram available* (1GB,2,4,8,16,32,64) in order to achieve a total of 1TB (or else 1024 GB) of total capacity.

How many possible combinations are there to achieve this? which is the most efficient way to find out?

*you could use each available capacity more than once obviously but I would also like your thoughts on the scenario were you could use them all the combinations of numbers of capacities you like + use just SOME of the group at your discretion e.g just 64 and 32GB sticks and none of the other capacities etc.

Comment: Problems here work much better if you have a specific question.  When you ask vaguely about "just some" you are asking for a much longer answer than fits here.  You have left out some important details-does every slot need to be used?  Does the total need to be exactly 1024 GB or is anything greater acceptable?  If you think about the question, often you can solve it yourself, or you can find a typical case that (on seeing a solution) will lead you to understand how to solve other cases.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) problem where there is a base case (Base Case: With $0$ slots, there is $1$ way to create $0$ GB of RAM) and induction (Induction: Using the number of ways to create any sum up to the maximum with $n-1$ slots, we can find the number of ways to get a sum to $s$ with $n$ slots by summing the number of ways to get a sum to $s-a$ with $n-1$ slots for all addends $a$). This is also similar to the [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), but instead of figuring out whether or not we can get a sum with $1024$ GB, we're finding the number of ways we can do so. This means that this problem is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness), which basically means the time to solve the problem grows very fast as the addends and/or the sum are added with more digits.

Thus, here is my dynamic programming algorithm for this problem in [Python](https://www.python.org/):

```
# These are our addends:
addends = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
# num_sums[num_addends][sum] is the number of ways sum can be found
# using num_addends addends
num_sums = []

# We iterate the number of addends from 0 to 49, not including 49:
for num_addends in range(49):
    # Append an array into num_sums for num_sums[num_addends]:
    num_sums.append([])
    for sum in range(1025):
        # If there are no addends,
        # then there is 1 way to add to 0
        # and 0 ways to add to anything else:
        if num_addends == 0:
            num_sums[num_addends].append(1 if sum == 0 else 0)
        # Otherwise:
        else:
            # At first, we have found 0 ways:
            num_sums[num_addends].append(0)
            # Loop through all the addends:
            for addend in addends:
                # If addend is bigger than sum,
                # exit because that means there is no way
                # to include addend in our sum:
                if addend > sum: break
                # Increment num_sums[num_addends][sum]
                # by the number of ways that sum-addend can be found
                # with num_addends-1 addends:
                num_sums[num_addends][sum] += \
                    num_sums[num_addends-1][sum-addend]

# Output the number of ways to sum to 3 GB with 2 addends.
# It is easy to show that this should be 2,
# so we know we did something wrong if our program does not output 2:
print(num_sums[2][3])
# Output the number of ways to sum to 1024 GB with 48 addends.
print(num_sums[48][1024])
```

Also, please note that my program accounts for the order in which the slots are filled , so the situation where $1$ GB is put in the first RAM slot and $2$ GB is put in the second RAM slot and the situation where $2$ GB is put in the first RAM slot and $1$ GB is put in the second RAM slot are treated as the different situation and are counted as $2$ ways to sum to $3$ with $2$ addends. Also, I leave no RAM slot empty, so each RAM slot has at least $1$ GB of RAM.

My program outputs $54725807780812926153007692867349522953$ as an answer, meaning that there are $54725807780812926153007692867349522953$ ways to sum to $1024$ GB using $48$ RAM slots with either $1$, $2$, $4$, $8$, $16$, $32$, and $64$ GB of RAM while account for the order in which the RAM slots are filled and leaving no RAM slot empty.

Comment: 0_0 this answer is amazing

Comment: Yeah. These kinds of problems can grow _really_fast, especially because I accounted for the order of how the slots are filled. If I did not account for order, the answer would likely have been orders of magnitude less, although still very big.

Answer (score 3):

> We can model this  and related problems with *[Generating Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)*.  The seven  different RAM  capacities can   be represented as
>   \begin{align*}
> x^1+x^2+x^4+x^8+x^{16}+x^{32}+x^{64}
> \end{align*}
>   with the exponent indicating the capacity and the coeffients of $x^n$ indicating the number of different possibilities with this capacity.
>   If    we  consider $48$ slots, we can model the number of different configurations (in mathematical terms, the number of *[compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics))*) as
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(x^1+x^2+x^4+x^8+x^{16}+x^{32}+x^{64}\right)^{48}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   Since we are interested in providing the user with $1\ TB = 1024\ GB$, we are looking for the coefficient of $x^{1024}$ in (1).
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^{1024}]&\left(x^1+x^2+x^4+x^8+x^{16}+x^{32}+x^{64}\right)^{48}\tag{2}\\
> &=[x^{1024}]\sum_{{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_7=48}\atop{k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_7\geq 1}}
> \binom{48}{k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_7}x^{k_1+2k_2+\cdots+64k_7}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{{{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_7=48}\atop{k_1+2k_2+\cdots+64k_7=1024}}\atop{k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_7\geq 1}}
> \frac{48!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_7!}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we could directly compute the number of possibilities as the coefficient of $x^{1024}$ in the polynomial provided we have a CAS which is powerful enough.
- Otherwise we can write the expression using *[multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)* as in (3)
- Since we need only the coefficient of $x^{1024}$ we can extract it as we did in (4) and reduce the problem to the calculation of two linear equations in $7$ integer variables $k_1,\ldots,k_7$.

Comment: (2) needs 20 seconds using Derive 6, and 5 using Mathematica. How would I approach (4)? Generate all partitions of 48, then filter the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly no simple closed form for the kind of question you're asking.  A less complex problem, [how to count the binary partitions of a number](http://theory.cs.uvic.ca/inf/nump/BinaryPartition.html), has [no closed solutions in OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=A000123). Your problem is more complex in that you limit the powers of $2$ for the RAM modules, and either limit the number of slots used to $48$ or require all $48$ slots used.

This python fragment enumerates distinct ways of partitioning a number using a specified list of 'pieces':

```
def partition(n, unsorted_pieces, max_pieces):
  def partition2(n, pieces, max_pieces):
    answer = set([()] if n == 0 else [])
    if max_pieces > 0 and len(pieces) > 0 and n <= max_pieces * pieces[0]:
      for k in range(0, min(n // pieces[0], max_pieces) + 1):
        for p in partition2(n - k * pieces[0], pieces[1:], max_pieces - k):
          answer.add((pieces[0],) * k + p)
    return answer
  return partition2(n, tuple(reversed(sorted(unsorted_pieces))), max_pieces)
```

Without regard to order of placement, and without necessarily filling all 48 slots, the number of ways of getting $1024$GB is:

```
print(len(partition(1024, [1,2,4,8,16,32,64], 48)))
142652
print(len(partition(1024, [32,64], 48)))
17
```

If all 48 slots need to be filled, the number of ways (without regard to order of placement) is:

```
print(sum([len(p) // 48 for p in partition(1024, [1,2,4,8,16,32,64], 48)]))
21716
print(sum([len(p) // 48 for p in partition(1024, [32,64], 48)]))
0
```